# SSDT 2012 Value does not fall within the expected range. (mscorlib)

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools, mscorlib

I've got a solution with a 2012 SSIS project included. I've also got a 2010 SSIS project included. Both was working well I was duplicating functionality from one project to another. After going offline from TFS i got the following error:

**Cannot show the editor for this task. (Microsoft Visual Studio)**

**Value does not fall within the expected range. (mscorlib)**

In EventViewer I got the following error this morning:
**Microsoft SSIS Service: 
Registry setting specifying configuration file does not exist.**

My research showed me it could be a permissions problem and I changed my Integration Services instance to use the NetworkService account.
I've also edited my registry key to reflect the correct path to the MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml file.
The error did not appear again however the problem still persists.

I've done a repair. Deleted SSDT 2012 along with the Data Tools enu and Build Utilities. Nothing helped.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Sounds like you had a package deployment model using a configuration file that referenced a registry key for it's settings. Select SSIS after you have opened the .dtsx file and check your package configurations.